# Log user in after account has been created and not to login screen using Okta flow

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, okta

When a new user is created, we need to get an id token instead of taking the user to the login screen.

This is how the flow works.

A new user is being created in our Express API using `@okta/okta-sdk-nodejs` package with `client.createUser`. Then when the user has verified the email and phone number using MFA, we call the `client.activateUser` method which returns an activationUrl and activationToken response.

In React, we're using the `@okta/okta-auth-js` package. On the login component,  after the user has received the sms verification code and it was correct, we call the `oktaAuth.token.getWithRedirec`t method, then on the same login component we're listening for `isRedirectUri` and then `oktaAuth.token.parseFromUrl()` we call the `oktaAuth.tokenManager.setTokens` method and then the user is already logged in.

My problem is that when the user has activated the account, we are redirecting the user to the login screen in order to sign in instead of getting a token and saving it in the local storage and take the user to the signed in pages. How can I get an ID token after activating the account? Either with `@okta/okta-auth-js` or `@okta/okta-sdk-nodejs`